# What devices are supported for bluetooth in OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth

I just tried to connect my stereo to my mac via bluetooth. However, my mac does not find the device. Is this expected? Which devices does OS X Mavericks support for bluetooth? Although bluetooth uses a common standard it does not necessarily mean that all devices that supports bluetooth are supported by any other bluetooth device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your hardware.

You can click on the Apple Menu - then about this mac then support (in the tabs in the window) then lastly User Manual.

[image]

From there, you can know your model year and model. Most OS X macs support the following profiles:

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10549

- A2DP
- AVRCP
- DUN
- FTP
- HCRP
- HSP
- HID
- OPP
- SPP